# Does ReadFile buffer need to be nulled?

Tags: c++, windows

The Windows ReadFile function ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx)) isn't clear on this point, but should the buffer be explicitly nulled beforehand?

```
DWORD dwLength = 255;
char acBuffer[255];
memset(&acBuffer[0], '\0', 255);    // Is this required?
ReadFile(HANDLE, acBuffer, dwLength, &dwLength, OVERLAPPED);
```

It seems to work reliably regardless of whether I initialise the buffer or not.

Comment: You need to initialize input parameters, not output parameters. However, you do need to initialize _pointers to_ output parameters. I.e. you can't pass an uninitialized pointer instead of `&dwLength`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should the buffer be explicitly nulled beforehand?

No. It will be filled with data up to the length given by `dwLength`, if there wasn't an error. As long as you check for errors and don't use the data in the buffer beyond `dwLength` you can't possibly have a problem.

> Or can I just use the buffer without initialisation?

Yes.